# Is it possible to get response after share post or feed in facebook?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook

I want to make functionality on website if user share post or feed in his account of our website than i want to authenticate user for further process.
means i want to authenticate user after registration process if he share post on FB then he can login.
how it possible by email address or other thing. we takes unique email address for registration.

website is developed using core PHP. it is better if solution done using javascript or PHP.

for your time,
Thank you!

Comment: No there is not.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to get a valid success response after a user shared something, or to know who shared something on his personal wall.

But what is more important: You are not allowed to allow users to login/authenticate only if he shared something on his personal wall.

Comment: Yes, but how can i know user shared something on his personal wall is there any way to know which user share post from our site, by using email id or etc ?

Comment: no, there is no way, you are not supposed to know - there is no valid/allowed use case for it anyway.